# Javascript Code not working in Chrome, but works everywhere else

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, click

I'm trying to call a jquery click function on a table header to sort it with the sortable plugin.

```
jQuery("#orderby").click();
```

This code is usually scheduled to work a few milliseconds after document ready because otherwise it wouldn't work. I was checking it on Firefox and all good. Then Chrome and nothing, Safari doesn't get it as well. I have checked IE and Opera and it does work well.

I tried it through the console in Chrome and it doesn't work either. Any idea what i could be missing? If you need extra details please ask.

```
<table title="Clasificaciones" summary="" class="leaguemanager standingstable sortable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="logo num">&nbsp;</th>
          <th>Equipo</th>
          <th id="orderby">GC</th>
          <th>Loc</th>
          <th>Vis</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="alternate ascend">
          <td class="logo"><img title="Logo" alt="Logo" src="#"></td>
          <td><a href="#">Cruz Azul</a></td>
          <td class="num">7</td>
          <td class="num">4</td>
          <td class="num">3</td>
        </tr>     
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
```

The above JS is all that is called.

Comment: If there aren't any JS errors, then we'll probably have to see the HTML and JS. More context.

Comment: Need to see more to be able to investigate. What does the targeted markup look like and can you provide a larger code context for your event trigger?

Comment: Yeah,  i just added the target HTML.

Comment: Why exactly are you scheduling the code to run a few milliseconds after document.ready?

Answer (score 0):

It the table header you are referring to a `<thead>` ? It's possible that Chrome doesn't handles click events on theads.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you are trying to simulate a click event on the table header. `click()` does not do this - this method is used for defining a click handler function.

Try using this code instead to simulate a click event on your table header:

```
jQuery("#orderby").trigger(jQuery.Event("click"));
```

Comment: he said it works on other browsers except chrome.. also click api:http://api.jquery.com/click/ : `Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.`